# How to remove Windows boot manager on one disk

Tags: windows, boot

I bought an alienware laptop with a single HDD and a windows 10 on it. I then bought an SSD and installed another windows 10. Both disks are GPT and I can see EFI partition in both disks.

Here's the problem, upon the laptop boots I can press F12 to enter the boot option and see two Windows Boot Manager, the 2nd one being the one I want to keep. But in the BIOS setup, where I can see and edit the boot device sequence, I can only see the 1st Windows Boot Manager.

Is there a safe way to remove the 1st Windows Boot Manager? Because I already deleted the old windows files on the HDD. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem myself.

Turns out the BIOS in my laptop allows the users to add/remove entries themselves. In the boot tab, there will be an option named similar to "Add file to boot options" and "Remove file from boot options".

1. Select "Add file to boot options".
2. Select the EFI partition in my SSD.
3. Select Boot/Bootx64.efi in that partition.
4. Done

And if I want to remove the entry in the HDD, I can do that too with the second option.

There might be some problem if you're not sure which is the EFI partition you want. You can either

1. Check each partition to find that Bootx64.efi file.

Or

2. Use command `GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | FL -property DriveLetter, DeviceID, Capacity` in PowerShell and you will know the volume signature (GUID) of that EFI partition. The EFI partition usually is the one with 100MB capacity if you allow Windows to format your SSD automatically during Windows installation. And the volume signatures are listed in the "Add file to boot option".